# BDE and Slovak language. Is there any driver for it?

Tags: delphi, bde, paradox

We have an application built in Delphi 5 which uses Paradox Tables and BDEADMIN.

One of our clients needs to use Slovakian Characters like `ž`

I've been googling all over and testing but I can't find the right language drivers in BDEADMIN to work correctly with it.

Is there a language driver for it or any compatible drivers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried Paradox Czech 852 or somethin alike? I understand it is "Czech", but BDE is old enough to not know about Slovakia - another good reason to abandon it.

Comment: IIRC, 852 was used for Czechoslovakia and was covering both Czech and Slovak characters. Windows ANSI equivalent was 1250. So you could try drivers containing the strings 852, Czech, 1250, e.g. 'Paradox Czech 852', 'Pdox ANSI Czech', or 'pdx ANSI ISO L_2 CZ'. Play with the available language drivers which are listed in the BDE Admin: Configuration\Drivers\Native\PARADOX\LANGDRIVER.

Comment: What is really your issue? What is your system and user locale? Delphi 5 is not Unicode, and handling different ANSI codepages may be an issue.

Comment: The issue is that I'm trying to write Czech characters like ž on persons names but I keep getting hash signs #